# Unable to add draggable element to a selected group

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/X8z6B/1/ - with three draggable boxes in a container that I've made selectable.  I can drag a rectangle around two of the boxes and select them but I can't CTRL-click the third box and select it.  It seems to be the drag handler that's getting in the way since it works fine if remove draggable() from the box (comment out line 35 in the jQuery).  Does anyone know how I can make the third draggable box selected with Ctrl-click?

Thanks

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id="box1" class="box">1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The modifier Ctrl+ is not necessary:

```
$(function () {
    $('.box').draggable();
    $('#container').selectable({});
    $('.box').click(function (){
        $(this).addClass("ui-selected");
    });
});
```

But if a modifier key is important for your case:

```
$(function () {
    $('.box').draggable();
    $('#container').selectable({});
    $('.box').click(function (e){
        if(e.metaKey){// might be ctrlKey, but metaKey is a Mac compatible 
            $(this).addClass("ui-selected");
        }
    });
});
```